# Remove preceding spaces and tabs from a given string in C language

Tags: c, string, tabs, spaces

What C function, if any, removes all preceding spaces and tabs from a string?

Comment: I have changed the title to match the text. Because it seems very unlikely to me that the word "preceding" was added by mistake.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C a string is identified by a pointer, such as `char *str`, or possibly an array. Either way, we can declare our own pointer that will point to the start of the string:

```
char *c = str;
```

Then we can make our pointer move past any space-like characters:

```
while (isspace(*c))
    ++c;
```

That will move the pointer forwards until it is not pointing to a space, i.e. after any leading spaces or tabs. This leaves the original string unmodified - we've just changed the location our pointer `c` is pointing at.

You will need this include to get `isspace`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

Or if you are happy to define your own idea of what is a whitespace character, you can just write an expression:

```
while ((*c == ' ') || (*c == '\t'))
    ++c;
```

Comment: Technically, this will move the pointer "c" to the first non-space character, assuming it started out at the start of the string.  It doesn't change the string at all.  I point this out because if you have another pointer to the start of the string, it will still point to the original start of the string which may have spaces in it.

To be clear, this technique is greatly preferred, since you're not moving bits around in the string, but you have to be aware you're moving the pointer, not eliminating the spaces.  You have to understand pointers well to understand the difference.

Comment: Good point, I've hopefully improved the explanation to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler function to trim white spaces

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * trim(char * buff);

int main()
{
    char buff[] = "    \r\n\t     abcde    \r\t\n     ";
    char* out = trim(buff);
    printf(">>>>%s<<<<\n",out);
}

char * trim(char * buff)
{
    //PRECEDING CHARACTERS
    int x = 0;
    while(1==1)
    {
        if((*buff == ' ') || (*buff == '\t') || (*buff == '\r') || (*buff == '\n'))
            { 
                x++;
                ++buff;
            }
        else
            break;
    }
    printf("PRECEDING spaces : %d\n",x);
    //TRAILING CHARACTERS
    int y = strlen(buff)-1;
    while(1==1)
    {
        if(buff[y] == ' ' || (buff[y] == '\t') || (buff[y] == '\r') || (buff[y] == '\n'))
            { 
                y--;
            }
        else
            break;
    }
    y = strlen(buff)-y;
    printf("TRAILING spaces : %d\n",y);
    buff[strlen(buff)-y+1]='\0';
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: I fixed a buffer overflow in `main` by initializing the `char` array the usual C way: the compiler does the copy for you at compile time.

Comment: Are you aware that OP asked only for `trimleft`?

Answer (score 0):

```
void trim(const char* src, char* buff, const unsigned int sizeBuff)
{
    if(sizeBuff < 1)
    return;

    const char* current = src;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(current != '\0' && i < sizeBuff-1)
    {
        if(*current != ' ' && *current != '\t')
            buff[i++] = *current; 
        ++current;
    }
    buff[i] = '\0';
}
```

You just need to give buff enough space.

Comment: Oops, I thought you wanted to remove "all" spaces and tabs in a given string. I missed "preceding". hope it helps someone else. :)

Comment: You can compress in situ since the output is smaller than the input.

Comment: My down vote is just a reminder for this cheep fix: incorporate the *to remove "all" spaces and tabs in a given string* from comment to answer text to clarify its relation to the question. BTW: don't forget to change tha name `trim` to something less misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can *setup a counter to count the corresponding number of spaces*, and accordingly shift the characters by that many spaces. Complexity for this ends up at **O(n)**.

```c
void removeSpaces(char *str) {
    // To keep track of non-space character count
    int count = 0;

    // Traverse the given string. If current character
    // is not space, then place it at index count
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            str[count++] = str[i]; // increment count
    str[count] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: There is the word *preceding* within the question text, now it's also in the title, so it's just a `trim_left` function. But your answer can easily be adjusted to that.