# What is the symbol for whitespace in C?

Tags: c, char, whitespace, space

I am trying to figure out how to check if a character is equal to white-space in C. I know that tabs are `'\t'` and newlines are `'\n'`, but I want to be able to check for just a regular normal space (from the space-bar) inside of an `if` statement.

Does anybody know what is the character for this?

Comment: `char a = ' ';` space is the character

Comment: Worth reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

Comment: It looks like everyone is forgetting that `'a'` has type `int` in C.

Comment: @Sinan: I had no clue that C and C++ disagreed on this!

Comment: @SinanÜnür But it doesn't actually affect the answers.

Comment: @kdopen  It does affect the correct use of `isspace()`, `isblank()`, etc.  These functions are not defined for `char`, but for `int` values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  Passing a `char` which is signed versus an  `int` can have different results depending on how the `int` value was assigned.

Comment: @Beko and to think, I googled it and came up here.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is no particular symbol for whitespace. It is actually a set of few characters which are:

```
' '      space 
'\t'     horizontal tab 
'\n'     newline
'\v'     vertical tab 
'\f'     form feed 
'\r'     carriage return
```

Use [`isspace`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isspace.html) standard library function from [`ctype.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/ctype.h.html) if you want to check for any of these white-spaces.

For just a space, use `' '`.

Comment: `isspace` would return affirmative for `'\t'`, which the OP doesn't want.

Comment: Assuming he wants to check for all whitespace characters, and not just space.

Comment: @Hurkyl The title of the question says *whitespace*. Maybe it is time to educate the OP about the difference between the space character, and the set of characters that are considered to be whitespace.

Answer (score 13):

The character representation of a Space is simply `' '`.

```
void foo (const char *s)
{
    unsigned char c;
    ...
    if (c == ' ')
        ...
}
```

But if you are really looking for all whitespace, then C has a function (actually it's often a macro) for that:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...

void foo (const char *s)
{
    char c;
    ...
    if (isspace(c))
        ...
}
```

You can read about `isspace` [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm)

If you really want to catch all non-printing characters, the function to use is `isprint` from the same library. This deals with all of the characters below 0x20 (the ASCII code for a space) and above 0x7E (0x7f is the code for DEL, and everything above that is an extension).

In raw code this is equivalent to:

```
if (c < ' ' || c >= 0x7f)
    // Deal with non-printing characters.
```

Comment: Pedantic: `char c; ... if (isspace(c))` is UB when `c < 0`.  Could use `if (isspace((unsigned char) c))`

Answer (score 8):

The ASCII value of `Space` is 32. So you can compare your char to the octal value of 32 which is 40 or its hexadecimal value which is 20.

`if(c == '\40')
{ ... }`

or

`if(c == '\x20')
{ ... }`

Any number after the `\` is assumed to be octal, if the character just after `\` is not `x`, in which case it is considered to be a hexadecimal.

Comment: `'\40'`, `'\x20'`, `32`, `' '` are all absolutely the same in an ASCII based C implementation. The same type (`int`). The same value. The same internal representation. The same (if any) padding. The same (if any) trap representations. Of all 4, only the last one is guaranteed to represent a space on every computer with a C implementation, whether it's ASCII-based, or EBCDIC-based, or KLINGON-based.

Comment: Do the \40 or \x20 or 32 need to be inside single quotes? I mean, single quotes are used for characters, and to me those three aren't really characters. They're integers. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

No special escape sequence is required: you can just type the space directly:

```
if (char_i_want_to_test == ' ') { 
    // Do something because it is space
}
```

In ASCII, space is code 32, so you *could* specify space by `'\x20'` or even `32`, but you really shouldn't do that.

Aside: the word "whitespace" is a catch all for space, tab, newline, and all of that. When you're referring specifically to the ordinary space character, you shouldn't use the term.

Answer (score 4):

To check a space symbol you can use the following approach

```
if ( c == ' ' ) { /*...*/ }
```

To check a space and/or a tab symbol (standard blank characters) you can use the following approach

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

if ( isblank( ( unsigned char )c ) ) { /*...*/ }
```

To check a white space you can use the following approach

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

if ( isspace( ( unsigned char )c ) ) { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

make use of isspace function .

> The C library function int isspace(int c) checks whether the passed
>   character is white-space.

sample code:

```
    int main()
    {

       char var= ' ';

       if( isspace(var) )
       {
          printf("var1 = |%c| is a white-space character\n", var );
       }
/*instead you can easily compare character with ' '  
  */     
    }
```

```
Standard white-space characters are −

' '   (0x20)    space (SPC)
'\t'    (0x09)  horizontal tab (TAB)
'\n'    (0x0a)  newline (LF)
'\v'    (0x0b)  vertical tab (VT)
'\f'    (0x0c)  feed (FF)
'\r'    (0x0d)  carriage return (CR)
```

source : [tutorialpoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm)

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int c,sp,tb,nl;
sp = 0;
tb = 0;
nl = 0;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
   switch( c )
{
   case ' ':
        ++sp;
     printf("space:%d\n", sp);
     break;
   case  '\t':
        ++tb;
     printf("tab:%d\n", tb);
     break;
   case '\n':
        ++nl;
     printf("new line:%d\n", nl);
     break;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: That's not the way to answer a question, and that's not the way to write a main() function prototype either.