# Char Matrix issues in C

Tags: c, matrix, printing, char

I'm a beginner in C and am currently experiencing some troubles invovling chars.
I'm having an issue trying to enter values in a char matrix and then print it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3

int main( )
{

char arr[N][N]={{0}};
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("%c",arr[i][j]);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

There are two chars that are missing at the end of the output.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I would like to understand my mistake:

-Is it some kind of problem involving the scanf fonction? I've heard about the buffer before, is that related? Is the problem coming from the moment I press enter?

-Am I initializing my matrix in a wrong way?

-Is it better to use getchar() in this situation? If so, how can I manage to enter exactly N*N values and not more?

Thanks a lot.
Jordan.

Comment: "There are two chars that are missing at the end of the output." --> posting the input, the output and the expected output are useful parts of post like these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `" %c"` to accept `char` as input. When you add a **space** before `"%c"` it consumes [white-spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30033598/2873538) (newline, tab, space, etc.) entered with previous inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3

int main() {

    char arr[N][N]={{0}};
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            scanf(" %c",&arr[i][j]);
            //     ^ --- the space before %c
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("%c ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
a b c d e f g h i
```

You can also input these characters one by one using <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> button.

**Output:**

```
a b c 
d e f 
g h i
```

You may also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6582322/2873538) post which addresses the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this.. Add getchar(); statement after scanf() statement.

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
        getchar();
    }
}
```

getchar() will consume tailling new lines.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just enter the 9 characters in sequence without pressing enter button like

```
123456789\n
```

because putting a newline character after each character is stored in one of character index becuase `\n` is a character itself which surely you don't want to be entered like this

```
1\n2\n3\n4\n5\
```

In above case only 5 characters would be taken from user intentionally.